# Can Euclid´s propostion in Book 1 proposition 1 be saved by using a special value for the radius?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

We know that Euclid in Book 1 proposition 1 made an error in that he uses the intersection of two circles which cannot be shown to exist, following his axioms.

If we imagine a closed spherical surface for example, we get intuitively the idea that at least one circle with a small enough radius can be found to fulfill his proposition for any geometry where the axioms would hold. Is that correct?

Comment: What do you mean "get intuitively the idea"? If we want an intuitive idea rather than axiomatic proof, then we shouldn't have any problems with Euclid's first proposition in the first place!

Comment: @Misha Lavrov, I see that e.g. on a sphere-like body as the Earth I could not get a intersection point on Earth for two circles with a radius larger than the diameter of the Earth, but two small circles might intersect. I certainly don't think that is a proof. However, this makes me wonder about the question i posed.

Comment: I see, so you're just seeing the sphere as motivation to ask the question. Unfortunately, circle-circle intersection can fail to hold in other models as well (and for that matter, there are other properties of spherical geometry we don't like, such as the behavior of lines and the order of points on those lines).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the Cartesian plane over the rational numbers: the set of points $(x,y)$ with $x,y \in \mathbb Q$. Define lines and circles as the solution sets to the usual equations.

Euclid's postulates all hold in this model (though more modern sets of axioms, such as Hilbert's, will not). However, Proposition I.1 does not hold: there are no equilateral triangles, no matter how small.

The proof fails because two circles that "ought to" intersect by their placement don't actually have any rational points in common. This, too, is a problem for arbitrarily small circles.

Comment: That is a good point!

Comment: Don't understand why you say there are no equilateral triangles. I can draw one on a piece of paper.

Comment: @rhody Your piece of paper is a different model of Euclid's postulates from $\mathbb Q^2$ :)

Comment: My ignorance I’m afraid, I don’t know what Q^2 is :(

Comment: @rhody It's the construction I'm describing in my answer: the plane that only contains points with rational coordinates. When coordinates can be real numbers, lots of equilateral triangles exist. But there is no equilateral triangle such that all three corners have rational $x$- and $y$-coordinates.